# Optics(interference)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, newtonian-mechanics, optics, geometric-optics, geometry

I'm a student at physics department, and I have a question about optics.

In interference phenomenon we have two experiments: one with name Michelson and the other is the double slit experiment.

In experiments the fringes will appear with different shapes. In Michelson they will be circles, and at double slit the fringe shape will be straight lines. I want the proof of different shapes mathematically and theoretically.

Answer (score 1):

Fringes occur because light going through different length paths will produce destructive or constructive interference. Destructive when the light arrives an integer plus one half wavelength later (and so a dark area) and constructive when the two paths are an integer number of wavelengths different.

In the double slit case, the paths start from two slits. So the paths are an integer number of wavelengths different along bands parallel to the slits. In effect, you are intersecting parallel cylinders centered on the slits, and so get lines parallel to the slits. When the difference in the radius of the 2 cylinders is exactly an integer number of wavelengths, a bright band.

In the Michelson case, the light is expanding in spherical wave fronts, and these go on different paths of different length. So here you are intersecting spheres. From the view point of the viewing plate at the center of the fringes, their centers are different distances away. When exactly an integer number away, you get a bright spot in the middle, when a half plus an integer, a dark spot.

Answer (score 0):

They are basically the same. In Michelson Morley experiment the circular fringes are right on top of each other and the interference comes and goes depending on the difference in length of the two arms of the interferometer. If you were to slightly offset the two circular fringes side by side on the screen so they still overlapped you would see the vertical straight lines your talking about.